# Activity instance still exists even after onDestroy() is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I pass a handler created on mainUI thread from `Activity` and passed to a thread which performs some network operation and when i obtain result i send the result back to the activity using the handler.

This approach had issue in memory leaks when i went through these links:
 [Inner ClassHandler Memory Leak](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) 
 [Android Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk/lIYDavGYn5UJ)

So i had implemented `WeakReference`, and kept the activity instance using `WeakReference`. But i am still seeing `Activity` instance alive even after activity is destroyed.

I created a `Handler` inside activity and passed activity instance as weakreference to handler. 
By the time my `Handler` responds with a message delivered to it after 10secs, `Activity` is destroyed. But the weak reference still has the `Activity` instance and i am seeing the `Toast`, after `Activity` is destroyed.

Is there some where my understanding wrong ?
 Can someone explain how to handle messages delivered to a handler,but the UI is not around ?

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public abstract class SingleParamHandler <T> extends Handler
{
private WeakReference<T> mActivityReference;

public SingleParamHandler(T activity) {
    mActivityReference = new WeakReference<T>(activity);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (mActivityReference.get() == null) {
        return;
    }
    handleMessage(mActivityReference.get(), msg);
}

protected abstract void handleMessage(T activity, Message msg);

}

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MyHandler<MainActivity> handler;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    handler = new MyHandler<MainActivity>(this);
    new Thread(new MyRunnable(handler)).start();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("######## Activity onDestroy() ###### ");
}

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Handler mHandler;
    public MyRunnable(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 1));
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private static class MyHandler<T> extends SingleParamHandler<T> {

    public MyHandler(T activity) {
        super(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(T act, Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == 1) {
            Toast.makeText((MainActivity)act, "Called after activity destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Based on the **response obtained**, i am updating the answer here. You may do it in the way u liked. But this is one way.

Added the below function in SingleParamHandler

```
public void clear() {
    mActivityReference.clear();
}
```

And in Activity onDestroy()

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("######## Activity onDestroy() ###### ");
    handler.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a `WeakReference` here. The `Handler` can just contain a reference to the `Activity`. In activity's `onDestroy()` just call a method on `MyHandler` that sets the reference to the `Activity` to `null`. Check for `null` in `handleMessage()`.

Another choice would be this: in activity's `onDestroy()` call a method that interrupts the sleeping thread so that it shuts down before sending the message.

Comment: Thanks for the logic. May i know, what makes you say weakreference is not needed, becoz the link which i posted says Handler needs to be static and make weakreference to the activity or service and check before handling message ? is not that contradicts ? Your knowledge on this would be appreciated..!!

Comment: @Mani This suggestion goes in the same direction as mine (registering/unregistering Activities). I was only making fewer assumptions. David, I still think in this simple scenario, it would be easier if the Handler checks for `Activity.isDestroyed()` instead, because `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to execute?

Comment: The article you linked to covers a specific situation, and I don't agree with everything that is written there. The case that is covered is a "delayed message" posted to a `Handler`. The article describes a case where a message is posted to a `Handler` that will de delivered in 10 minutes. This message has a reference to the `Handler` and the `Handler` has a reference to the `Activity` and that implies that neither the `Handler` nor the `Activity` will be able to be removed by the garbage collector **while this message is still in the queue**.

Comment: The author goes on to say that this causes a _massive memory leak_. Actually, this only "leaks" memory for 10 minutes (until the message is delivered, at which point the garbage collector can then remove the message, the `Handler` and the `Activity`). Personally I wouldn't call this a **massive memory leak**, as it fixes itself in 10 minutes. In your case, as long as you clean up everything yourself (which you are doing in `onDestroy()`) there is no leak.

Comment: @Mani You _can_ use a weak reference, but you already discovered its downside, namely that it does _not_ tell you when the object really dies, and that's what you want to know (or so do I understand your question). So if you do _not_ use a weak reference but a regular one, and set that to _null_ at the exact point in time, you're telling _both_ the garbage collector _and_ your program logic when the object is dead.

Comment: @ClassStacker first of all, `isDestroyed()` is only available from API level 17, which means it won't work on most devices in the field; Second, `isDestroyed()` only returns `true` if the `onDestroy()` has already been called on the `Activity`, so that makes it useless in the case where `onDestroy()` hasn't been called by the Android framework; Thirdly, the only cases I have seen where `onDestroy()` is **not called** are when Android decides to kill off the process in order to reclaim resources. In that case, we don't care, because the `Activity`, `Handler` and everything else will be dead.

Comment: @ClassStacker Thanks for the response. The Activity.isDestroyed() api is available from only api version 17, which makes it less usable in lower version.But i would try setting the activity to null in onDestroy() and observe.

Comment: @DavidWasser Right. Then we're back at the usual attach/detach scheme.

Comment: @DavidWasser . Your explanation is awesome...!! Indeed both of you...!!

Answer (score 3):

There's no guarantee that Android will really delete an object from memory if it's not required to do so. In other words, Activity objects can stay in memory even after `onDestroy()` has been called (if there's enough memory available). On the other hand, there's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` *will* be called if there's not enough memory; quite to the contrary, Android is allowed to kill your whole process after calling `onPause()` on your current Activity (depending on the Android version).

I think there's a better path to follow for your purpose. What you may want to do is *attach*, *detach* and possibly *re-attach* (e.g. on configuration changes) Activities to your Service. Don't hope for the garbage collector to do the work for you. Rather, make it explicitly.

Subclass `Activity` and override the lifecycle methods as well as `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` to let your Service know who's in charge right now. Of course, that's only a best-effort approach since some callbacks aren't guaranteed, but that only matters in certain situations which aren't dangerous. For example, your Activity won't detach from your Service in `onPause()`, but it could get killed right afterwards. But either your Service runs in the same process, so it gets killed at the same time. Or it runs in a different process, but then Android will notice the broken connection and may or may not kill the service as well; if not, then all you need to do is implement it in a robust fashion to be able to deal with the connection loss.

**Update**

After reading your comment: You're right, I didn't address that specifically.

> i am figuring out how to avoid messages being sent to a handler which is created in a activity which is destroyed

Given your code above, and assuming that you really just want to display `Toast`s with an Activity as long as it exists, the following approach should help.

- If your `Thread` is supposed to serve more than one Activity, extend it such that Activities can register with the Thread after it is created. If your `Thread` just serves one `Activity`, pass the `Activity` reference along with the `Handler` reference upon your `Thread`'s (`Runnable`'s) construction.
- Before your `Thread` sends the message via the `Handler`, check `activity.isDestroyed()`. If the Activity is not destroyed, send the message. If the Activity is destroyed, do not send the message.
- Depending on whether your Thread should server more than one Activity, either exit it's `Runnable`'s `run()` method or set it's `Activity` reference to `null` if it finds that the `Activity` has been destroyed.

This should fix your above code. However, if your scenario grows, other approaches may be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the resopnse. I understand that Activity instance wont be deleted becoz onDestroy() has been called. But i am figuring out how to avoid messages being sent to a handler which is created in a activity which is destroyed...!! I know handler is not tied to Activity, it is to main UI thread, but wondering how to handle this ?

Comment: @Mani Updated my answer, Hope it helps!